# python3: Python could not understand the code in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a python newbie and just got an error while running Python code.
My code is:

```
import sys


def main():
if sys.argv[1] == "call":
    print("call")
else
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

and got:

```
  File "test.py", line 42, in main
    else
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    Did you forget a colon `:`?

A `SyntaxError` occurs when Python cannot understand your code.

Python could not understand the code in the file
```

Comment: You have `is` instead of `if`...

Answer (score 0):

While Python is based on indentation, some block requires a colon (`:`) in addition to the indentation.
Quoting from [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-colons-required-for-the-if-while-def-class-statements):

```
Why are colons required for the if/while/def/class statements?
The colon is required primarily to enhance readability (one of the results of the experimental ABC language). Consider this:

if a == b
    print(a)
versus

if a == b:
    print(a)
Notice how the second one is slightly easier to read. Notice further how a colon sets off the example in this FAQ answer; it’s a standard usage in English.

Another minor reason is that the colon makes it easier for editors with syntax highlighting; they can look for colons to decide when indentation n
```

Back to our example: the `else` statement is missing a colon at the end of the line

```
import sys


def main():
is sys.argv[1] == "call":
    print("call")
else:
    print(sys.argv[1])
```